# What do "power" attacks actually do?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What difference do power attacks make?

I use double daggers and doing a power attack takes lots of stamina but doesn't seem to give me any advantages, other than a nice animation.

Are there any difference between 1 handed and 2 handed (duel wielded) power attacks?

Comment: Power attacks while sneaking do a lot more damage, especially with Assassin's Blade perk  and the Shrouded Gloves (from the Dark Brotherhood). ALL 3 hits will get the x30 bonus. Could be the difference between waking up a mob and an one shot kill.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Power_Attack#Power_Attacks), power attacks do double damage and have a chance of staggering the opponent.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the increased damage/stagger chance, you can also get perks to further improve your power attacks, including such things as sweep attacks against all enemies in front of you (with 2-h weapons) or a chance to behead enemies (with 1-h weapons).